# Dynamically creating associative arrays in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I have a variable (`$OUTPUT`) that contains the following name / value pairs:

```
member_id=4611686018429783292
platform=Xbox
platform_id=1
character_id=2305843009264966985
period_dt=2020-11-25 20:31:14.923158 UTC
mode=all Crucible modes
mode_id=5
activities_entered=18
activities_won=10
activities_lost=8
assists=103
kills=233
average_kill_distance=15.729613
total_kill_distance=3665
seconds_played=8535
deaths=118
average_lifespan=71.72269
total_lifespan=8463.277
opponents_defeated=336
efficiency=2.8474576
kills_deaths_ratio=1.9745762
kills_deaths_assists=2.411017
suicides=1
precision_kills=76
best_single_game_kills=-1
```

Each line ends with `\n`.

I want to loop through them, and parse them into an associative array, and the access the values in the array by the variable names:

```
while read line
do
    key=${line%%=*}
    value=${line#*=}

    echo $key=$value
    data[$key]="$value"

done < <(echo "$OUTPUT")

#this always prints the last value
echo ${data['seconds_played']}
```

This seems to work, i.e. `key/value` print the right values, but when I try to pull any values from the array, it always returns the last value (in this case `-1`).

I feel like im missing something obvious, but have been banging my head against it for a couple of hours.

**UPDATE**: My particular issue is I'm running a version of `bash` (3.2.57 on OSX) that doesn't support associative arrays). I'll mark the correct answer below.

Comment: what does `typeset -p data` show?

Comment: `${data['seconds_played']}`? I get a syntax error

Comment: On MacOS, install bash version 5 with [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) -- it's really quite simple.

Comment: Yeah, I updated it. Was trying to make something that used default shell, since this is an example for other people to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try declaring `data` as an associative array before populating it, eg:

```
$ typeset -A data                   # declare as an associative array
$ while read line
do
    key=${line%%=*}
    value=${line#*=}

    echo $key=$value
    data[$key]="$value"

done <<< "${OUTPUT}"

$ typeset -p data
declare -A data=([mode]="all Crucible modes" [period_dt]="2020-11-25 20:31:14.923158 UTC" [deaths]="118" [best_single_game_kills]="-1" [efficiency]="2.8474576" [precision_kills]="76" [activities_entered]="18" [seconds_played]="8535" [total_lifespan]="8463.277" [average_lifespan]="71.72269" [character_id]="2305843009264966985" [kills]="233" [activities_won]="10" [average_kill_distance]="15.729613" [activities_lost]="8" [mode_id]="5" [assists]="103" [suicides]="1" [total_kill_distance]="3665" [platform]="Xbox" [kills_deaths_ratio]="1.9745762" [platform_id]="1" [kills_deaths_assists]="2.411017" [opponents_defeated]="336" [member_id]="4611686018429783292" )

$ echo "${data['seconds_played']}"
8535
```

Answer (score 4):

Without `declare -A data`, then `data` is a normal array. In normal arrays expressions in `[here]` first undergo expansions, then arithmetic expansion. Inside arithmetic expansion unset variables are expanded to `0`. You are effectively only just setting `data[0]=something`, because `data[$key]` is `data[seconds_played]` -> variable `seconds_played` is not defined, so it expands to `data[0]`

Add `declare -A data` and it "should work". You could also just:

```
declare -A data
while IFS== read -r key value; do
    data["$key"]="$value"
done <<<"$OUTPUT"
```

Comment: if i declare -A data or typeset -A data, i get this error: "declare: -A: invalid option". Im on bash 3.2.57 (on OS X)

Comment: `bash 3.2.57` your bash just doesn't support associative arrays. It's too old

Comment: Well, i guees thats the issue then. Ill try it in zsh, although its already giving me some errors.